# Unable to enable mpm-event in httpd | centos 7

Tags: php, centos7, php-fpm, httpd, php5

I am kind of new to mpm and all so please don't mind.
I have a web server running 8 websites (php based) on it. And my RAM usage goes over 90 % and the swap usage goes over 80 %. And when i check

> service httpd status

the number of request generally bounces to 30k and i see a lot of httpd processes.
i tried to fix it via searching google and trying out this [solution](https://anime.my/tutorials/mod_fcgid-fastcgi-php-centos-6-vps-quick-guide/) thinking that enabling php-fpm and mod_mpm_event will take all the loads off my RAM and SWAP, but it didn't work and the sites loaded [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNtaq.jpg) where as the original site looked [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IboTg.jpg). So,
i reverted to my old configurations.

my configurations:

00-mpm.conf

```
[root@csmsvr-lin-lv-02 conf.modules.d]# cat 00-mpm.conf
# Select the MPM module which should be used by uncommenting exactly
# one of the following LoadModule lines:

# prefork MPM: Implements a non-threaded, pre-forking web server
# See: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/prefork.html
LoadModule mpm_prefork_module modules/mod_mpm_prefork.so
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    ServerLimit                  800
    StartServers                  5
    MinSpareServers          75
    MaxSpareServers         800
    MaxRequestWorkers    800
    MaxRequestsPerChild  0
</IfModule>
# worker MPM: Multi-Processing Module implementing a hybrid
# multi-threaded multi-process web server
# See: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/worker.html
#
#LoadModule mpm_worker_module modules/mod_mpm_worker.so

# event MPM: A variant of the worker MPM with the goal of consuming
# threads only for connections with active processing
# See: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/event.html
#
#LoadModule mpm_event_module modules/mod_mpm_event.so
```

/etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf

```
[root@csmsvr-lin-lv-02 conf.modules.d]# cat /etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf
#
# Cause the PHP interpreter to handle files with a .php extension.
#
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>

#
# Allow php to handle Multiviews
#
AddType text/html .php

#
# Add index.php to the list of files that will be served as directory
# indexes.
#
DirectoryIndex index.php

#
# Uncomment the following lines to allow PHP to pretty-print .phps
# files as PHP source code:
#
#<FilesMatch \.phps$>
#    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
#</FilesMatch>

#
# Apache specific PHP configuration options
# those can be override in each configured vhost
#
php_value session.save_handler "files"
php_value session.save_path    "/var/lib/php/session"
```

00-base.conf

```
 [root@csmsvr-lin-lv-02 conf.modules.d]# cat 00-base.conf
#
# This file loads most of the modules included with the Apache HTTP
# Server itself.
#

LoadModule access_compat_module modules/mod_access_compat.so
LoadModule actions_module modules/mod_actions.so
LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
LoadModule allowmethods_module modules/mod_allowmethods.so
LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
LoadModule auth_digest_module modules/mod_auth_digest.so
LoadModule authn_anon_module modules/mod_authn_anon.so
LoadModule authn_core_module modules/mod_authn_core.so
LoadModule authn_dbd_module modules/mod_authn_dbd.so
LoadModule authn_dbm_module modules/mod_authn_dbm.so
LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
LoadModule authn_socache_module modules/mod_authn_socache.so
LoadModule authz_core_module modules/mod_authz_core.so
LoadModule authz_dbd_module modules/mod_authz_dbd.so
LoadModule authz_dbm_module modules/mod_authz_dbm.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule authz_owner_module modules/mod_authz_owner.so
LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
LoadModule cache_module modules/mod_cache.so
LoadModule cache_disk_module modules/mod_cache_disk.so
LoadModule data_module modules/mod_data.so
LoadModule dbd_module modules/mod_dbd.so
LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
LoadModule dumpio_module modules/mod_dumpio.so
LoadModule echo_module modules/mod_echo.so
LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
LoadModule expires_module modules/mod_expires.so
LoadModule ext_filter_module modules/mod_ext_filter.so
LoadModule filter_module modules/mod_filter.so
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
LoadModule include_module modules/mod_include.so
LoadModule info_module modules/mod_info.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule logio_module modules/mod_logio.so
LoadModule mime_magic_module modules/mod_mime_magic.so
LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
LoadModule negotiation_module modules/mod_negotiation.so
LoadModule remoteip_module modules/mod_remoteip.so
LoadModule reqtimeout_module modules/mod_reqtimeout.so
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule slotmem_plain_module modules/mod_slotmem_plain.so
LoadModule slotmem_shm_module modules/mod_slotmem_shm.so
LoadModule socache_dbm_module modules/mod_socache_dbm.so
LoadModule socache_memcache_module modules/mod_socache_memcache.so
LoadModule socache_shmcb_module modules/mod_socache_shmcb.so
LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so
LoadModule substitute_module modules/mod_substitute.so
LoadModule suexec_module modules/mod_suexec.so
LoadModule unique_id_module modules/mod_unique_id.so
LoadModule unixd_module modules/mod_unixd.so
LoadModule userdir_module modules/mod_userdir.so
LoadModule version_module modules/mod_version.so
LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so

#LoadModule buffer_module modules/mod_buffer.so
#LoadModule watchdog_module modules/mod_watchdog.so
#LoadModule heartbeat_module modules/mod_heartbeat.so
#LoadModule heartmonitor_module modules/mod_heartmonitor.so
#LoadModule usertrack_module modules/mod_usertrack.so
#LoadModule dialup_module modules/mod_dialup.so
#LoadModule charset_lite_module modules/mod_charset_lite.so
#LoadModule log_debug_module modules/mod_log_debug.so
#LoadModule ratelimit_module modules/mod_ratelimit.so
#LoadModule reflector_module modules/mod_reflector.so
#LoadModule request_module modules/mod_request.so
#LoadModule sed_module modules/mod_sed.so
#LoadModule speling_module modules/mod_speling.so
```

httpd -l

```
[root@csmsvr-lin-lv-02 conf.modules.d]# httpd -l
Compiled in modules:
  core.c
  mod_so.c
  http_core.c
```

SYS config:
RAM- 6 GB
SWAP- 6 GB
CPU- 8 Core
php -v: 5.4.16
httpd -v : 2.4.6

Answer (score 0):

The image you provide show that you didn't have a PHP handler set up (correctly).
You should be able to use (in 00-base.conf):

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_fcgi_module modules/mod_proxy_fcgi.so
```

Then make sure the following is not commented:

```
LoadModule mpm_event_module modules/mod_mpm_event.so
```

Finally you need to change:

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

To:

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/path/to/your/documentroot/$1
DirectoryIndex /index.php index.php
```

Make sure you use the correct `/path/to/your/documentroot`. Also, php-fpm needs to be running (and listening on 127.0.0.1 port 9000) for this to work. If it doesn't work, look in de logs of both Apache and PHP-FPM. Usually these are located in `/var/log/httpd` and `/var/log/php-fpm`.

Comment: i changed the php.conf in /etc/conf.d/php.conf and commented out the set handler part and added the proxy pass match, still it didn't work. I next added the proxy pass to each virtual host and only one site was accessible but the images ddn't load.

Comment: i am getting an error php_value misspelled when i enable the mpm_event module. Searching a lot i think i came to a conclusion that, 'mpm-event and workers cannot be used in my case where the scripts need php_value' and there is only chance of using it if i upgrade php to 7. am i right ?

Comment: No, it is still possible to set this, but you need to do it in a different place.
Have a look at https://secure.php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.configuration.php .
This shows you can set `php_flag[display_errors] = off` in the PHP-FPM pool configuration.

Comment: my websites have php_value and php_flag variables defined in the .htaccess files. enabling mom_event shows error that php_value is misspelled. I looked at your answer and i just want to confirm, you are saying that if i define the php_value and php_flag in the file /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf then this issue can be tackled ?